# Detecting longpress and preventing clicks with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, onclick, content-script

I'm writing an chrome extension which allows users to longpress links in any webpage and when that happens link is opened in iframe injected by chrome extension instead of opening link inside webpage or new tab. When user clicks somewhere else on body (not a link) it should hide the injected iframe.

This is the code I came up with, which works correctly on 99% websites, but I have problem with websites like reddit.com, which trigger navigation in webpage by clicking on elements different than links (basically anywhere you click (post header, container div etc.) it would take you to the post, and that hides my iframe because of code in `bodyClickListener` function.

```
// number of milliseconds required for triggering longpress
const LONGPRESS_TIME = 500;

// Create variable for setTimeout for longpress
let openLinkTimeout;

// each 500ms check for new links in DOM and attach listeners to them
setInterval(attachClickListeners, 500);

// attach click listeners
function attachClickListeners() {
    // add click listener to body
    document.body.addEventListener("click", bodyClickListener);

    // add click listeners to links
    let links = document.querySelectorAll("a:not(.myExtensionLink)");

    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        let link = links[i];

        link.className = (link.className + " " + "myExtensionLink").trim();

        link.addEventListener(
            "mousedown",
            function(e) {
                console.log("MOUSE DOWN");
                // if left click
                if (e.button == 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    openLinkTimeout = setTimeout(openLink, LONGPRESS_TIME, link.href);
                }
            },
            true
        );

        // catch onclick events
        link.onclick = clickListener;
    }
}

// take care of left click
function clickListener(e) {
    // if left click, and link was opened in blade, prevent default click behaviour
    if (e.button == 0 && !openLinkTimeout) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        clearTimeout(openLinkTimeout);
        openLinkTimeout = null;
        return false;
    } else {
        clearTimeout(openLinkTimeout);
        openLinkTimeout = null;
        return true;
    }
}

// listen for clicks on body, and hide iframe if it isn't A (link) element
function bodyClickListener(e) {
    if (document.querySelector("#myExtensionIframe") && e.target.tagName != "A") {
        hideIframe();
    }
}

// cancel timeout and open link in iframe
function openLink(href) {
    clearTimeout(openLinkTimeout);
    openLinkTimeout = null;

    openInIframe(href)
}
```

Comment: So you want to prevent non-link clicks on reddit.com? Or what?

Comment: @wOxxOm If you go to reddit index page and click anywhere on the post excerpt, it would take you to the post page. With my code posted above, if I long press link  to post on reddit page, it successfully opens in my iframe, but as soon as I release the left mouse button, reddit detects click on some of links parent or children elements (I console.log it and sometims it's h2, sometimes it's div etc.) and takes user to post's page. 
I want that when any link is longpressed, it opens in iframe and prevent website to navigate to that link.

Comment: Also, clicking on any element in page after iframe is opened should close the iframe. And this should work on all websites (so I need general solution, not just for reddit, but it's the first website where I experienced this behaviour)

Comment: Try to be the first listener by attaching to window, using mousedown, and capturing phase like this window.addEventListener('mousedown', callback, true) -- then you can do event.stopImmediatePropagation() + event.preventDefault() and hopefully stop the site's handlers.

Comment: @wOxxOm OK, after a lot of time losing my nerves, I came to the conclusion that the thing triggering navigation of reddit's webpage is actually the iframe I inject and the URL I load in it! You can try it by yourself just by pasting this code into console on reddit's webpage and waiting for few seconds:
```
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

iframe.src = "https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyPL/comments/dhv5cu/kdb_spotted_in_training_monday_14th_october/";

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Maybe you have some idea how to prevent websites from doing this weird thing?